# Method of moments and MLE estimates for Lomax (Pareto Type 2)

Tags: maximum-likelihood, fitting, method-of-moments, pareto-distribution

I have [this](https://statmath.wu.ac.at/%7Ehornik/QFS2/Data/Theft.txt) dataset, on which I am supposed to fit Lomax distribution with MM and MLE. Lomax pdf is:
$$f(x|\alpha, \lambda) = \frac{\alpha\lambda^\alpha}{\left(\lambda+x\right)^{\alpha+1}}$$
For MM, it is possible to show that:
$$\hat{\alpha}=\frac{2\hat{\sigma}^2}{\hat{\sigma}^2-\bar{X}^2}$$
$$\hat{\lambda}= \bar{X}\frac{\hat{\sigma}^2+\bar{X}^2}{\hat{\sigma}^2-\bar{X}^2}$$
Where $\hat{\sigma}^2$ is the sample variance and $\bar{X}$ is sample mean. The estimates are:

```
df <- read.table('Theft.txt')
df <- df$V1

s <- var(df)
m <- mean(df)

alpha <- (2*s)/(s-m^2)
lambda <- m*((s+m^2)/(s-m^2))

> alpha
[1] 2.70862
> lambda
[1] 3451.911
```

For MLE, I have log-likelihood function:
$$\ell(\alpha, \lambda|x) = n\log(\alpha)+\alpha n\log(\lambda) - (\alpha+1)\sum_{i=1}^{n}\log(\lambda+x_i)$$

and the implementation:

```
llik <- function(alpha, lambda,x){
  n<-length(x)
  res <- n*log(alpha)+n*alpha*log(lambda)-(alpha+1)*sum(log(x+lambda))
  return(-res)
}
mle1 <- mle(minuslogl = llik, start = list(alpha=alpha,lambda=lambda),
fixed = list(x=df), method = 'BFGS')
> mle1@coef
      alpha      lambda 
   2.860708 3451.907162
```

I used as starting values the MM estimates. The resulting coefficients are quite similar to MM, however after using `flomax()` function from `Renext` package, I am getting completely different estimates, with higher likelihood:

```
> flomax(df)
$estimate
      shape       scale 
   1.880468 1872.132104
```

I have also done some simulations, in which both MM and MLE are really bad at estimating the 'real' parameters of Lomax. Why are these estimates this bad? Why is in my case MM so different from MLE? Why is `mle()` so sensitive to starting values?

Comment: Have you tried calculating the values of the log likelihood function for the different parameter estimates?  That might give you some insight into what is happening.

Comment: yes, for the `mle` function the log-likelihood is -1013, for `flomax` it is -1012, so `flomax` does better.

Comment: My guess is that the LF is very flat for a large region around the optimum, so it's easy for optimization functions to find no significant improvement from a step and just stop.  You might want to try to plot a 3D wireframe or some such for the log LF as a function of shape and scale just to see.

Comment: Also note that $\lambda$ is a scale parameter; if you divide all your data by $1000$, it'll put the resultant scale parameter at about the same magnitude as the shape parameter, which difference may also be causing problems.

Comment: The rescaling did the trick for me, BTW.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue appears to be the greatly different scales of the two parameters and how that interacts with BFGS.  When I try `optim` using BFGS on the raw data, I get similar results to `mle` above (not surprisingly):

```
x <- df / 1000

llik <- function(theta, x){
   alpha <- theta[1]
   lambda <- theta[2]
   n<-length(x)
   res <- n*log(alpha)+n*alpha*log(lambda)-(alpha+1)*sum(log(x+lambda))
   return(-res)
}

alpha <- 2.7
lambda <- 3450    
mle1 <- optim(c(alpha, lambda), llik, method="BFGS", x = 1000*x)

mle1$par
[1]    2.859574 3449.996428
```

But working with the rescaled data:

```
alpha <- 2.7
lambda <- 3.450
mle1 <- optim(c(alpha, lambda), llik, method="BFGS", x = x)

mle1$par
[1] 1.880470 1.872135

llik(c(mle1$par[1], 1000*mle1$par[2]), 1000*x)
[1] 1012.211
```

Using a different technique (Nelder-Mead) on the original data gives good results, although we really ought to rewrite the log likelihood function so as to not fail when negative values of the two parameters are passed:

```
alpha <- 2.7
lambda <- 3450

mle1 <- optim(c(alpha, lambda), llik, method="Nelder-Mead", x = 1000*x)
Warning messages:
1: In log(alpha) : NaNs produced
2: In log(alpha) : NaNs produced
3: In log(alpha) : NaNs produced
4: In log(alpha) : NaNs produced
5: In log(alpha) : NaNs produced
6: In log(alpha) : NaNs produced
7: In log(alpha) : NaNs produced

mle1$par
[1]    1.879401 1870.984994
```

Comment: Thanks, that's nice! Do you know why are the Lomax estimates so far from each other? Even when you do a simulation, the bootstrapped standard errors are huge both for MLE and MM

Comment: Those are two different, but related, questions.   The first has to do with the internals of the BFGS algorithm, the different scales of the parameters, and the fact that the likelihood function is quite flat over a large range of parameter values, the second is due just to the flatness of the LF.  I may expand on my answer later...

Comment: Through its argument `control` the `stats::optim` function allows to give a `parscale`  vector (as an element of the list passed) which scales the parameters. So using `c(1, 1000)` in `parscale` does the job for your example. This can be used in MLE as soon as a parameter is a scale parameter and the scaling of the data is avoided. This is a very nice feature which lacks in many other optimisation functions.